# Mass-assignment issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please, explain, how can I make records in database with several methods, changing attributes I DON'T want to be `attr_accessible`.

For example, in User Model:

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :guest
```

I don't want 'admin' true or false row be placed here because of security issue

Comment: maybe you want to permit to change admin row only for administrator, so use `attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :guest, :admin, as: :admin` and then update `update_attributes({admin: true}, as: :admin)` (mass assigment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the attribute manually, for example if your model is named User you can do the following :

```
user = User.first
user.update_attributes(attributes_hash)
user.admin = true
user.save
```

attr_accessible is used only for mass assignment via update_attributes for example, but you can always assign a specific property by calling it directly like in my example above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be asking how to change the admin attribute in your test or development environment without adding it to `attr_accessable`.

One way would be the `toggle` method. For example,

```
user = User.first
user.admin?
=> false
user.toggle!(:admin)
user.admin?
=> true
```

A couple of things about `toggle` to consider. The attribute must be passed as a symbol and all callbacks and validations are skipped. In other words use caution for anything outside of testing and development. So this is how you can mass-assign the admin attribute without adding it to `attr_accessable`.